# grep search for any number in a range

Tags: grep, search

So I have a file with a number of records that look like the following:

```
Peugeot:206:2000:Red:1
```

And I'm trying to grep search for any that contain a year 1995-1999. I have tried

```
grep '[1995-1999]' file.txt
```

to no avail. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Wont `grep -E '199[5-9]'  file.txt` do it?

Comment: yes it does, also `egrep "199[5-9]" file.txt `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This one** is easy:

```
grep -E "199[5-9]"
```

does the job. It is easy, because the intended number range matches a character code range. For a more complicated example, e.g., 1998-2003, you will have to split the range appropriately:

```
grep -E "199[8-9]|200[0-3]"
```