# How to use wc, grep and ls to list all files that are at least 10,000,000 bytes in a directory?

Tags: command-line, wc

Now I find that wc -c could show the size of file, then how to select them and list them?
It should be a single pipeline of commands.

Comment: Also [web search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Aunix.stackexchange.com+find+files+bigger+larger+better&atb=v142-7__&ia=web)

Comment: Note that using `wc` to find the sizes of really big files is just masochism. It would need to read the whole file and count each individual byte.  The file size information is already stored as meta-data in the directory.

Comment: Better use the faster "du" command instead of "wc". `du -b` does the same as `wc -c` (output in bytes).

Comment: Related: [grep search for any number in a range](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/244140/grep-search-for-any-number-in-a-range)

Answer (score 3):

`find` will be better:

```
find . -type f -size +9999999c
```

Replace `.` with the directory.

Comment: Modified to also print the file sizes in bytes and sorted by file size (largest files first): `find . -type f -size +9999999c -print0 | xargs -0 du -b | sort -nr`